# CUDA Support with MicrosoftML in R

Tags: r, cuda, microsoft-r

I want to execute the rxNeuralNet function from the MicrosoftML Package for R with the option acceleration = "gpu". However, R fails to enable the GPU accelaration as it prints the following message:

> Beginning processing data.
>   Failed to initialize CUDA runtime. Possible
>   reasons:
>   1. The machine does not have CUDA-capable card. Supported devices have compute capability 2.0 and higher.
>   2. Outdated graphics drivers. Please install the latest drivers from http://www.nvidia.com/Drivers.
>   3. CUDA runtime DLLs are missing, please see the GPU acceleration help for the installation instructions.

I do have a Nvidia GPU with the latest drivers including CUDA 8.0 installed. I also copied the required dll files into the proper as stated in the help document. The target directory for the dlls is:

```
C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Client/R_SERVER/library/MicrosoftML/mxLibs/x64
```

The dlls that I copied into this directory were:

> cublas80_65.dll cudart80_65.dll cusparse80_65.dll cudnn80_65.dll

Did I miss something? Unfortunately CUDA is still not working for rxNeuralNet. My OS:Win7_64Bit and GPU: Nvidia 950ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicrosoftML only supports CUDA 6.5 right now. This is noted in `?rxNeuralNet`, if somewhat obscurely. Make sure you download the correct versions from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-65 and https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive.

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve my issue. I renamed the files *64_80.dll to *64_65.dll and rxNeuralnet recognized my GPU as a CUDA capable GPU. I was also able to run some code on the GPU using rxNeuralnet.Thanks again for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are basic instructions.  Make sure to follow those exactly.

For GPU acceleration there are additional manual setup steps are required:

- Download and install NVidia CUDA Toolkit 6.5 (CUDA Toolkit).
- Download and install NVidia cuDNN v2 Library (cudnn Library).
- Find the libs directory of the MicrosoftRML package by calling system.file("mxLibs/x64", package = "MicrosoftML").
- Copy cublas64_65.dll, cudart64_65.dll and cusparse64_65.dll from the CUDA Toolkit 6.5 into the libs directory of the MicrosoftML package.
- Copy cudnn64_65.dll from the cuDNN v2 Library into the libs directory of the MicrosoftML package.